# How do I improve Google mobile vision API text recognition?

Tags: android, computer-vision, ocr

[Here is the screenshot of the result I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bViRu.png)

I used Mobile vision API and tried text recognition for this image, but it's not working. Should I use something like rotation? How to improve text recognition? I just want to recognize "GOOD MORNING" from images.

Answer (score 0):

Try your API after thresholding and remove small dots.

Refer below codes.

[image]

```
Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(templImage, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Imgproc.threshold(image, image, 215, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

Mat eroded = new Mat();
Imgproc.erode(image, eroded, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(3,2)));
Imgproc.dilate(eroded, eroded, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(2,2)));
```